# Struts 2 Jquery delete a row

Tags: struts, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

Can anyone help me deleting a row from  Struts 2 Jquery grid using an external button.
I have  included a button in the jsp as below

```
<sj:a id="delete" name="delete" onClickTopics="rowselect"
    button="true">Delete</sj:a>
```

and in the script tag I have written

```
$.subscribe('delete', function(event,data) {
    $("#gridedittable").jqGrid(‘delRowData’,row_id);
}
```

I am not able to get the `rowid` for the selected row to be deleted.
Can any one help me with this as I am new to struts 2 jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can get selected row by using the `jqGrid` api

```
$.subscribe('delete', function(event,data) {
    var rowid = $("#gridedittable").jqGrid(‘getGridParam’,'selrow');
    $("#gridedittable").jqGrid(‘delRowData’,row_id);
}
```

This assumed you set the `multiselect` param to `false`.

For `multiselect` , you have to use the option `selarrrow` instead.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

And the grid setting should be like

```
 <s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsontable"/>
    <sjg:grid
        id="gridtable"
        caption="Customer Examples"
        dataType="json"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        pager="true"
        gridModel="gridModel"
        rowList="10,15,20"
        rowNum="15"
        rownumbers="true"
    >
        <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="ID" key="true" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="Name" sortable="true"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="country" index="country" title="Country" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="city" index="city" title="City" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="creditLimit" index="creditLimit" title="Credit Limit" formatter="currency" sortable="false"/>
    </sjg:grid>
```